# Can't be applied to bigint, varchar in Athena

Tags: sql, left-join, amazon-athena, varchar, bigint

```
Select Id, sr_no from table_a a
Left join table_b b
On a.id=b.sr_no
```

#Note id is bigint and sr_no is string in Athena.

I am getting error like cannot be applied to bigint, varchar while querying the data.
I have also tried cast but it is still not working.

Any suggestion/help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You can't compare unlike types. Show the version with explicit `CAST` that is "still not working" and also the error you get for that one.

Comment: Error which I was getting is mentioned in subject.I am able to use cast (a.id as varchar) =b.sr no.

Comment: By the way thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

You should cast either the `bigint` to `varchar` or the other way around. For example:

```
Select Id, sr_no from table_a a
Left join table_b b
On a.id=cast(b.sr_no as bigint) 
-- or alternatively:
-- on cast(a.id as varchar) = b.sr_no
```